# В чем разница?

Tags: c, gcc

Есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int height;
    scanf("%i", &height);
    int spaces = height - 1, symbols = 1;
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 1; i <= height; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= spaces; ++j)
            printf(" ");
        for (k = 1; k <= symbols; ++k)
            printf("#");
        spaces = spaces - 1;
        symbols = symbols + 2;
        printf("\n");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Скомпилировав его в Windows + VS2010 и например ввести 7, то получу:

[image]

А проделав тоже самое но в debian + gcc я получу:

[image]

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Вы что-то не договариваете. Gcc не скомпилировал бы код с <windows.h>

Comment: Проверяйте код в отладчике ^_^

Comment: ну так там не windows.h, а Windows.h (в линуксе такие фокусы можно делать).
Предположу, что в этом файле переопределен printf или другие функции. Правда пока не могу придумать как именно, но есть идеи, как сделать такое поведение.

Comment: Само собой без Windows.h в gcc компилирую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я скомплировал ваш код в Ubuntu 11.04 (убрав соответственные строчки). Всё заработало как надо, без проблем.

Comment: +1, openSUSE, gcc 4.5.0.

Comment: Проблема в дебиане моем значит. Спасибо.